# Geofence_service package on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I more or less have copied the exact example code from the package and just removed the activity code as I do not need to track the users activity. All I am trying to achieve is once the user enters the geofenced area a button become available for them to select something, besides that it would just be static text until they get close enough. As of right now it seems as if I am in a constant wait state in the Stream even when I have my emulator position right on top of one of the data points. It seems to never update. Any insight as to why this is happening would be great!

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geofence_service/geofence_service.dart';
import 'package:greener_omaha/widgets/Loading.dart';

import '../helpers/modalButtonListHelper.dart';

class GeoFence extends StatefulWidget {
  final document;
  final String siteType;
  final Color color;
  const GeoFence({Key? key, required this.document, required this.siteType, required this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _GeoFenceState();
}

class _GeoFenceState extends State<GeoFence> {
  //final _activityStreamController = StreamController<Activity>();
  final _geofenceStreamController = StreamController<Geofence>();

  // Create a [GeofenceService] instance and set options.
  final _geofenceService = GeofenceService.instance.setup(
      interval: 5000,
      accuracy: 100,
      loiteringDelayMs: 60000,
      statusChangeDelayMs: 10000,
      useActivityRecognition: true,
      allowMockLocations: false,
      printDevLog: false,
      geofenceRadiusSortType: GeofenceRadiusSortType.DESC);

  // Create a [Geofence] list.
  List<Geofence> _geofenceList = <Geofence>[
    /*Geofence(
      id: 'place_1',
      latitude: 35.104971,
      longitude: 129.036023,
      radius: [
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_100m', length: 100),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_25m', length: 25),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_250m', length: 250),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_200m', length: 200),
      ],
    ),
    Geofence(
      id: 'place_2',
      latitude: 35.104971,
      longitude: 129.034851,
      radius: [
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_25m', length: 25),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_100m', length: 100),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_200m', length: 200),
      ],
    ),*/
  ];

  // This function is to be called when the geofence status is changed.
  Future<void> _onGeofenceStatusChanged(
      Geofence geofence,
      GeofenceRadius geofenceRadius,
      GeofenceStatus geofenceStatus,
      Location location) async {
    print('geofence: ${geofence.toJson()}');
    print('geofenceRadius: ${geofenceRadius.toJson()}');
    print('geofenceStatus: ${geofenceStatus.toString()}');
    _geofenceStreamController.sink.add(geofence);
  }

  // This function is to be called when the location has changed.
  void _onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    print('location: ${location.toJson()}');
  }

  // This function is to be called when a location services status change occurs
  // since the service was started.
  void _onLocationServicesStatusChanged(bool status) {
    print('isLocationServicesEnabled: $status');
  }

  // This function is used to handle errors that occur in the service.
  void _onError(error) {
    final errorCode = getErrorCodesFromError(error);
    if (errorCode == null) {
      print('Undefined error: $error');
      return;
    }

    print('ErrorCode: $errorCode');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _geofenceService.addGeofenceStatusChangeListener(_onGeofenceStatusChanged);
      _geofenceService.addLocationChangeListener(_onLocationChanged);
      _geofenceService.addLocationServicesStatusChangeListener(_onLocationServicesStatusChanged);
      _geofenceService.addStreamErrorListener(_onError);
      _geofenceService.start(_geofenceList).catchError(_onError);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildGeofenceMonitor();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    //_activityStreamController.close();
    _geofenceStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _buildGeofenceMonitor() {
    List<Geofence> siteLocations=[];
    siteLocations.add(Geofence(
      id: widget.document["docId"],
      latitude: widget.document["geo_loc"].latitude,
      longitude: widget.document["geo_loc"].longitude,
      radius: [
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_100m', length: 100),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_25m', length: 25),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_250m', length: 250),
        GeofenceRadius(id: 'radius_200m', length: 200),
      ],
    ));
    setState(() {
      _geofenceList = siteLocations;
    });
    return StreamBuilder<Geofence>(
      stream: _geofenceStreamController.stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext ctx) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 100,
                        color: widget.color.withOpacity(.75),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment:
                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: modalButtonList(
                              ctx, widget.document["docId"], widget.siteType),
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
              child: Text(
                "Update",
                style: TextStyle(color: widget.color, fontSize: 16),
              ));
        }else {
          return Loading(argColor: widget.color,);
        }


      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried hard coding the geofence to be right on top of my position and with my physical device but the stream still stays in a waiting state